# Reaction of acids with water

Tags: acid-base, water, hydrogen

Here is the reaction of $\ce{HCl}$ with $\ce{H_{2}O}$ I found on a website

$$\ce{HCl  + H_{2}O -> H^{+}(aq) + Cl^{-}}(aq)$$
However, in my text-book, the reaction is given as

$$\ce{HCl + H_{2}O -> H_{3}O^{+} + Cl^{-}}$$
Can anyone tell me what's going on here ? Which one is correct ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium

Comment: Both are correct. Moreover, in fact both are the same.

Comment: @IvanNeretin could you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I think I have to disagree. Bare protons are way too much **polarizing power** to exist without binding to solvent molecules (in this case it's $\ce{H2O}$).

Comment: Odd that Community♦ redirected the duplicate to another duplicate.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Exactly. That's why, in my opinion, "being solvated" for a proton in water means almost the same as "being H3O+".

Comment: @IvanNeretin I guess I misinterpreted your statement then. :)